# Unable to open MS Word document in Window Service in C#

Tags: c#, service

In my Window Service, I am opening MS Word document by the following line:

```
doc1 = WordApp.Documents.Open(UpFile, ReadOnly: true);
```

I am using:

```
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

The same code works fine in Console Application but not working in Window Service. Any suggestions?
I wan't my code to run at a specific time in a day so I am creating Window Service. Any other alternative?

(My code opens word documents and calculates line/word/character count/date last saved/last commented by)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Using interop in this scenario is [really not a good idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233971/is-using-interop-the-recommended-method-when-auto-generating-office-documents).

Comment: @teovankot Error is: An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005

Comment: @MariumMalik i gess your service just doesn't have rights. Where is the file located? Just run you service under user that can open file

Comment: @teovankot  File is in C

Comment: @MariumMalik check can user that run your service open file

Comment: @teovankot Yes, file can be opened. I will still try to change the path and check. Thanks